# Lint throwing errors for optional chaining only when running npm script

Tags: javascript, babeljs, eslint, optional-chaining

I have currently added [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) capability to my React project.

This is now working fine when I run my project.

But when I perform `npm run lint`, it still complains `Unexpected token` for following syntax.

```
const myVar = value1?.value2?.value3;
```

I believe it has to do with my lint script inside package.json file which is as follows.

```
"lint": "eslint --ignore-path .eslintignore --ext js,jsx,snap,md .",
```

Is there something I need to modify here?

The following are the changes I had to do to be able to use optional chaining. Please advice.

Inside .babelrc

```
{
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining"]
}
```

Inside .eslintrc

```
{
  "parserOptions": {
    "parser": "babel-eslint",
    "ecmaVersion": 2020
  }
}
```

Inside package.json

```
  "devDependencies": {
    .... others
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining": "^7.16.7", // added
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0", // added
    "eslint": "^7.5.0", // updated version
    "eslint-plugin-babel": "^5.3.0", // added
  },
```

For reference, these are most of the scripts inside my package.json file.

```
  "scripts": {
    ... other scripts
    "prebuild": "npm run clean",
    "build": "--clientConfig webpack/client.config.js --serverConfig webpack/server.config.js",
    "clean": "rimraf build",

    "lint": "eslint --ignore-path .eslintignore --ext js,jsx,snap,md .",
    
    "test:unit": "jest --testPathIgnorePatterns browser a11y",
  },
```

Comment: It should be called `.babelrc`. Maybe that's where the problem is.

Comment: @Andy Thats a typo in this question. Updated.